# Google Gears Browser Support

Tags: firefox, browser, safari, google-gears

I've just tried to install Google Gears and been told that neither Firefox 3.5.1 nor Safari 4.0.2 are supported.

The browser support page lists both browsers as options but on the basis of "or later" (so Firefox 1.5 +) so I assume that these versions are too new.

Anyone with any experience of using Gears know how quickly they support new versions?  There doesn't seem much point in installing it if everything I upgrade my browser (generally as soon as possible) it breaks Gears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google have been quite slow to release gears for Firefox 3.5, as it only came out about a week ago. I've a feeling that the plugin will work with no changes for 3.5.1, but we'll have to wait for them to release an update.

I've been getting most of my information about this from [this google group](http://groups.google.com/group/gears-users/browse_thread/thread/1c11eb7bca12ee3e/1c47afcf86231332).

Answer (score 0):

There's an unofficial build [here](http://code.google.com/p/gearsff35osx/downloads/list) that works with Firefox 3.5.1 on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/gears-users/browse_thread/thread/36537d4f47c5495c?pli=1) of a google gears browser that works in Safari. I wish the standard google gears install page offered it.